# Jenkins EC2 slave SSH failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, amazon-ec2

Using the Jenkins EC2 plugin, I cannot get my Jenkins master to SSH to my Jenkins slave. The slave spins up and provisions properly, but:

`INFO: Connecting to 10.99.3.6 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Feb 24, 2016 5:13:27 PM hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud log
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: There was a problem while connecting to 10.99.3.6:22`

Though the Jenkins host claims to be failing when attempting to ssh to the slave node, I am able to ssh from a shell on the Jenkins host without error, and using the same authentication keys as specified in my configuration.

I have additionally attempted to add and `id_rsa` file containing the same key inputted in the EC2 configuration in a `.ssh` directory in the Jenkins home dir, and the `ec2-user` home dir, which also did not work (which wasn't entirely unexpected).

Jenkins - v1.649

Amazon EC2 Plugin - v1.31

Using in-house Centos7.1 AMIs

Additional information:  The slave instance ID is listed in the build executor box, but says "offline" next to it, even after I observe the instance in the EC2 console as running and available, and am able to SSH to it manually from the master.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, this was an issue using Centos7 and JDK1.8.  When using the same configurations with Centos6.5 and JDK1.7, the slaves spun up and connected properly.

Comment: Hi! How did you figure this issue out? I am experiencing the EXACT same issue, but no idea where to look. I mean, these logs are not nearly enough. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Please add ***id_rsa.pub*** key from the master host's .ssh folder to ***authorized_keys*** on the slave host.

Comment: Well I'm trying to configure it so that it spins up a new instance with every build, and then terminates it after inactivity. The instance spins up, but then the above error is repeatedly dumped into the log until I kill the build.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug by some steps below:

1. Check security group of EC2, to be certain that port 22 was opened.
2. Use file *.pem to authenticate your EC2 on Jenkins server.